# What can I do to avoid Syncronous AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this Array

```
var testFlows = ["test1","test2","test3","test4","test5"];
```

I'm trying to get the inputs one by one and generating some html (the html generated doesn't really matter).

What matters is that I want to see this html panels by the order of the testFlows array. My code is completely random. If I refresh the page they are on different positions.

One solution would be to make a synchronous ajax but it's deprecated and bad, so what else can I do?

Code:

```
 var testFlows = ["test1","test2","test3","test4","test5"];

  $.each(testFlows, function (index, testFlow) {
            //get the inputs
            $.ajax({
               url: '/flow/getInputs',
               type: 'post',
               data: {testCaseName: testFlow.testCase.name},
               success: function (inputNames) {
                   testCaseAccordion = '<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapseTitle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-' + testFlow.testCase.name + index + '">' + testFlow.testCase.name + '(' + testFlow.testCase.type.name + ') <span id="eyeIcon" class="fas fa-eye float-right"></span></a></h4></div>';
                   testCaseAccordion += '<div id="collapse-' + testFlow.testCase.name + index + '" class="panel-collapse collapse"><div id="panel-body-' + testFlow.testCase.name + index + '" class="panel-body"></div></div>';
                   $('#accordion').append(testCaseAccordion);
                   if (testFlow.params !== null) {
                       var inputs = testFlow.params.split(',');
                       for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                           $('#panel-body-' + testFlow.testCase.name + index).append('<strong class="color-red">' + inputNames[i] + ': </strong>' + inputs[i] + '<br>');
                       }
                   }
                   else {
                       $('#panel-body-' + testFlow.testCase.name + index).append("This test case doesn't have any inputs");
                   }
               }
            });

        });
```

Comment: If I make my code with `async: false,` it works. But I don't want that

Comment: Send all data (ie. the entire array) in a single request, then loop as needed through the array you return from the request

Comment: I would suggest using promises.

Comment: There's **really** no need **to randomly bold** various parts of **your** question and it's **kind of annoying** to read.

Comment: I agree with Rory. Do not make 10 HTTP requests when you can make only one, sending an array containing 10 elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use promises, for example, in your case:

```
var testFlows = ["test1","test2","test3","test4","test5"];

function success(testFlowAndInputNames, index) {
    var testFlow = testFlowAndInputNames[0];
    var inputNames = testFlowAndInputNames[1];
    var testCaseAccordion = '<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="panel-title"><a class="collapseTitle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse-' + testFlow.testCase.name + index + '">' + testFlow.testCase.name + '(' + testFlow.testCase.type.name + ') <span id="eyeIcon" class="fas fa-eye float-right"></span></a></h4></div>';
    testCaseAccordion += '<div id="collapse-' + testFlow.testCase.name + index + '" class="panel-collapse collapse"><div id="panel-body-' + testFlow.testCase.name + index + '" class="panel-body"></div></div>';
    $('#accordion').append(testCaseAccordion);
    if (testFlow.params !== null) {
        var inputs = testFlow.params.split(',');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            $('#panel-body-' + testFlow.testCase.name + index).append('<strong class="color-red">' + inputNames[i] + ': </strong>' + inputs[i] + '<br>');
        }
    }
    else {
        $('#panel-body-' + testFlow.testCase.name + index).append("This test case doesn't have any inputs");
    }
}


var arrayOfPromises = testFlows.map(function (testFlow) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/flow/getInputs',
            type: 'post',
            data: {testCaseName: testFlow.testCase.name},
            success: resolve
        });
    })
    .then(function(inputNames) { 
        return [testFlow, inputNames];
    })
});

Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)
    .then(function(results) {
        results.forEach(success)
    });
```

Comment: Not at all, the promises API guarantee ordering WHEN all requests are completed. Which Promise.all does

Comment: I understand you and you got it backward, promises will complete in a random order, but Promise.all will order them. So rendering is in order.

Comment: You're entirely correct. My mistake. Sorry about that. I'd still recommend the OP make a single request, though.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `ajax` returns a promise, so you could save all the promises into an array, eg:

```
var testFlows = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5"];

var testFlowsPromises = $.map(testFlows, function(testFlow, index) {
  //get the inputs
  return $.ajax({
    url: '/flow/getInputs',
    type: 'post',
    data: {testCaseName: testFlow.testCase.name}
  }).then(function(inputNames) {
    return {
      inputNames: inputNames,
      testFlow: testFlow
    };
  });
});
```

Then, wait until all of them are done:

```
$.when.apply($, testFlowsPromises).done(function() {
  $.each(arguments, function(index, data) {
    // do stuff with index, data.inputNames, data.testFlow
  });
});
```

Now you'd have an array of ajax data in the same order.

**DEMO**:

https://jsbin.com/fixuxezale/edit?js,console

Comment: where do I put the $.when.apply? Outside everything?

Comment: yup outside of everything

Comment: Note that this does not guarantee the order of responses as the OP states is a requirement

Comment: can you explain? once all the requests are done, the order of the responses is the same as the order the requests were made.

Comment: Added an example on jsbin, the response order is guaranteed.